# How to PlaySound in C++ using Windows API?

Tags: c++, winapi, playsound

I try to play a music file in my coding, but failed. I have my music file in the same folder which save .cpp file.

Can someone help me?

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <windows.h>

int main() { 
    PlaySound("kenny g.WAV", NULL, SND_ASYNC);    
}
```

Comment: What is the error code you are getting with GetErrorCode() function?

Comment: i'm not sure about the GetErrorCode()

but the error message is

[Linker error]undefined reference to 'PlaySound@12'
id returned 1 exit status

Comment: You need winmm.lib to play music as Luis mentioned

Answer (score 15):

You need to use the absolute path, make sure that you're sending a filename (use SND_FILENAME flag), and pause the program long enough to play the sound file (e.g., use getchar()). You need to link the winmm.lib library in your project settings, and #include windows.h and mmsystem.h in the header.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>

int main() {
    PlaySoundA((LPCSTR) "C:\\kenny g.WAV", NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
    getchar();
}
```

API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712879(VS.85).aspx
That should be it. Let me know, thanks!

Comment: How would you compile that example under gcc/windows?

Answer (score 8):

try adding -lwinmm to your compiler settings thingy. It worked for me. Just type that in the compiler options area and it will work.

Comment: thanks and we have to add it to **Linker** settings not in compiler settings.

Comment: thanks it helped me out

Answer (score 2):

Can you use absolute path and check if it is path error?

```
Ex: PlaySound("C:\\kenny g.WAV", NULL, SND_ASYNC);
```

Comment: did you link to the required lib?

Answer (score 1):

```
int main() { 
    PlaySound("kenny g.WAV", NULL, SND_ASYNC); 
}
```

With the `SND_ASYNC` flag your program can (and it will) terminate immediatelly!

Try `PlaySound("kenny g.WAV", NULL, SND_SYNC);` first to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking about the path, your data file should be where your executable is, not where your source file is, if the path is not absolute.

And yeah, this very question has been [asked](http://forums.devx.com/archive/index.php/t-82438.html) 9 years ago ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can test by PlaySound(TEXT("SystemStart"), NULL, SND_ALIAS);

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it is unresolved yet!
You need to include the two header files mentioned in previous comments, link the project to the required lib and place the sound file in the same folder as your .exe file (in case you are not using the full path)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it works for me. Also For code::Block use winmm in linker settings.

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <windows.h>
#include <MMSystem.h>
 int main(){
PlaySound(TEXT("your file path.wav") , NULL , SND_SYNC) ;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. All what they say is correct but it won't play unless you removed the spaces in the file name. make it just like test.wav and it will work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).