# VC++ play sound

Tags: visual-c++, audio

I need C++ code to play sound at particular decibels that are choose by user dynamically.

Comment: Try this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565439/how-to-playsound-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was answered [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565439/how-to-playsound-in-c)

You need to use the absolute path, make sure that you're sending a filename (use SND_FILENAME flag), and pause the program long enough to play the sound file (e.g., use getchar()). You need to link the winmm.lib library in your project settings, and #include windows.h and mmsystem.h in the header.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>

int main() {
    PlaySound((LPCSTR) "C:\\kenny g.WAV", NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
    getchar();
}
```